# Minecraft Not Using All of RAM

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My Minecraft has been crashing a lot lately. I've tried everything, batch files, going into the Control Panel settings, all I could. This is the problem:

When I play Minecraft, I turn on my F3 view. The RAM will go up and up in percentage until it reaches 20% of RAM being used. It will then go back down to 8%. But if it gets to **21%** or RAM being used, the game will crash.

How do I fix this problem?

**Edit:** I was going through my Downloads folder and found three Java error messages, most likely from Minecraft. Here is the message:

**Second Edit:** Somebody asked me to determine if I had the path set up correctly by informing me to do the following:

> An easy way to determine this is fire up your CMD and type java -d64 -version. If it returns a successful message, you should be running the 64-bit version of Java.

The result was the command box displayed that it was an unrecognized function and could not run the JVM. I'm guessing it is because the path is not set up properly. How do I set the path to the 64 bit version of Java so I can use it with Minecraft?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x4e30fe65, pid=4892, tid=7508
#
# JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig4icd32.dll+0x44fe65]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x4c3a4c00):  JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7508, stack(0x4b530000,0x4b580000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000000

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000, EDX=0x00000008
ESP=0x4b57ef70, EBP=0x4b57f0fc, ESI=0x4d8a54a0, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x4e30fe65, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4b57ef70)
0x4b57ef70:   4d942d40 4e30febc 000084c0 3dffeb85
0x4b57ef80:   3f600000 4e3598fc 000084c0 51732cec
0x4b57ef90:   00000015 00200000 00250000 00000000
0x4b57efa0:   00000000 40300000 00000000 40300000
0x4b57efb0:   00000000 3fc80000 00000000 3ff00000
0x4b57efc0:   a3d70a3d 3fbffd70 00000000 3ff00000
0x4b57efd0:   00000000 00000000 4b57f9d4 02708530
0x4b57efe0:   00000000 00000000 00000000 3fb00000 

Instructions: (pc=0x4e30fe65)
0x4e30fe45:   01 89 4a 08 eb 20 85 c0 74 06 c7 00 ff ff ff ff
0x4e30fe55:   8b 8e b8 02 00 00 6a 10 51 8b ce e8 0b 7b 05 00
0x4e30fe65:   c7 00 10 00 5c 01 f3 0f 10 44 24 0c 8b 54 24 08
0x4e30fe75:   f3 0f 11 40 08 f3 0f 10 44 24 10 89 50 04 f3 0f 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000008 is an unknown value
ESP=0x4b57ef70 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4c3a4c00
EBP=0x4b57f0fc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x4c3a4c00
ESI=0x4d8a54a0 is an unknown value
EDI=0x00000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x4b530000,0x4b580000],  sp=0x4b57ef70,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.nglDrawArrays(IIIJ)V
J  adz.a()I
J  ct.a()V
J  l.a(Lacq;Z)Z
J  lr.a(FJ)V
J  lr.b(F)V
J  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.x()V
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run()V+40
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x4bac6c00 JavaThread "File IO Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2140, stack(0x6aa90000,0x6aae0000)]
  0x4b83cc00 JavaThread "Client write thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6728, stack(0x5d440000,0x5d490000)]
  0x4b83bc00 JavaThread "Client read thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7320, stack(0x52eb0000,0x52f00000)]
  0x4b83b800 JavaThread "Thread-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5560, stack(0x526e0000,0x52730000)]
  0x4b83b000 JavaThread "Thread-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7340, stack(0x524b0000,0x52500000)]
  0x4b810800 JavaThread "Thread-10" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6032, stack(0x52440000,0x52490000)]
=>0x4c3a4c00 JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7508, stack(0x4b530000,0x4b580000)]
  0x4c3a4400 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6660, stack(0x4b1d0000,0x4b220000)]
  0x4c0c4c00 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7868, stack(0x4cd90000,0x4cde0000)]
  0x4c24ec00 JavaThread "SwingWorker-pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7652, stack(0x4da00000,0x4da50000)]
  0x00259c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=7376, stack(0x02380000,0x023d0000)]
  0x4c133000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=7404, stack(0x4caf0000,0x4cb40000)]
  0x4a733800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3500, stack(0x4a950000,0x4a9a0000)]
  0x4a733000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5404, stack(0x4afe0000,0x4b030000)]
  0x4a730000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5164, stack(0x4af10000,0x4af60000)]
  0x4a5ce800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7680, stack(0x4acd0000,0x4ad20000)]
  0x4a5ca400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7796, stack(0x4a7d0000,0x4a820000)]
  0x4a5c5400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7644, stack(0x4ab00000,0x4ab50000)]
  0x4a5c2000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5808, stack(0x4aa40000,0x4aa90000)]
  0x4a56ac00 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7828, stack(0x00360000,0x003b0000)]
  0x4a566000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7500, stack(0x4a8e0000,0x4a930000)]

Other Threads:
  0x4a561800 VMThread [stack: 0x00ae0000,0x00b30000] [id=7432]
  0x4a5e4400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x4ae60000,0x4aeb0000] [id=7460]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 157376K, used 101940K [0x043d0000, 0x0ee90000, 0x19920000)
  eden space 139904K,  60% used [0x043d0000, 0x0964d268, 0x0cc70000)
  from space 17472K, 100% used [0x0cc70000, 0x0dd80000, 0x0dd80000)
  to   space 17472K,   0% used [0x0dd80000, 0x0dd80000, 0x0ee90000)
 tenured generation   total 349568K, used 46390K [0x19920000, 0x2ee80000, 0x443d0000)
   the space 349568K,  13% used [0x19920000, 0x1c66daf8, 0x1c66dc00, 0x2ee80000)
 compacting perm gen  total 16128K, used 15879K [0x443d0000, 0x45390000, 0x483d0000)
   the space 16128K,  98% used [0x443d0000, 0x45351ea0, 0x45352000, 0x45390000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x023d0000, 0x02a08000, 0x043d0000)
 total_blobs=3111 nmethods=2752 adapters=293 free_code_cache=26410Kb largest_free_block=27041856

Dynamic libraries:
0x00b50000 - 0x00b7f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\javaw.exe
0x76f60000 - 0x770e0000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x757c0000 - 0x758d0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x75df0000 - 0x75e36000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x744f0000 - 0x74524000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk.dll
0x764f0000 - 0x76590000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x75930000 - 0x759dc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x76110000 - 0x76129000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x765b0000 - 0x766a0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x74640000 - 0x746a0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x74630000 - 0x7463c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x75bc0000 - 0x75cc0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x76340000 - 0x763d0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x75b50000 - 0x75b5a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x76070000 - 0x7610d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x71a70000 - 0x71c0e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x746a0000 - 0x746f7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x75b60000 - 0x75bc0000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x759e0000 - 0x75aac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x694d0000 - 0x6958e000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x68320000 - 0x68648000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x72a60000 - 0x72a67000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x76140000 - 0x76175000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76f30000 - 0x76f36000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x6f0e0000 - 0x6f112000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x76130000 - 0x76135000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x69730000 - 0x6973c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x69690000 - 0x696b0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\java.dll
0x69670000 - 0x69683000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x681d0000 - 0x68312000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\awt.dll
0x753d0000 - 0x7545f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75660000 - 0x757bc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x6fbd0000 - 0x6fc50000     C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x70a60000 - 0x70a73000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x74700000 - 0x7534a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x69640000 - 0x6966a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x69620000 - 0x69634000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\net.dll
0x71e70000 - 0x71eac000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x717f0000 - 0x717f6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x696c0000 - 0x696cf000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x71e60000 - 0x71e65000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x71dd0000 - 0x71e14000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x71d90000 - 0x71db1000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x71d70000 - 0x71d8c000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x71d60000 - 0x71d67000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x71d30000 - 0x71d57000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x71ce0000 - 0x71ce6000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x71cf0000 - 0x71d28000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x71ef0000 - 0x71f06000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x71eb0000 - 0x71eeb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x744c0000 - 0x744d7000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x744b0000 - 0x744bb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x71e50000 - 0x71e60000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x71e40000 - 0x71e50000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x71e20000 - 0x71e32000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x71dc0000 - 0x71dc8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x694b0000 - 0x694d0000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x68190000 - 0x681c1000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\t2k.dll
0x75fb0000 - 0x76033000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6e460000 - 0x6e55b000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x702b0000 - 0x702fc000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x68110000 - 0x68141000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x75460000 - 0x755fd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x76040000 - 0x76067000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x76590000 - 0x765a2000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x706e0000 - 0x707d5000     C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
0x6a5b0000 - 0x6a620000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x720c0000 - 0x720d9000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x728d0000 - 0x728db000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x70680000 - 0x7068a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x694a0000 - 0x694a6000     C:\Windows\system32\IconCodecService.dll
0x69490000 - 0x69499000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x75e90000 - 0x75fad000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x75ab0000 - 0x75abc000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x4b270000 - 0x4b2db000     C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives\lwjgl.dll
0x68040000 - 0x68108000     C:\Windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x69430000 - 0x69452000     C:\Windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x63c30000 - 0x63d17000     C:\Windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x69480000 - 0x69486000     C:\Windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x72a50000 - 0x72a59000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x68180000 - 0x68186000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin\jawt.dll
0x68170000 - 0x68177000     C:\Windows\system32\atiglpxx.dll
0x4dec0000 - 0x4eb9c000     C:\Windows\system32\ig4icd32.dll
0x68160000 - 0x6816b000     C:\Windows\system32\atigktxx.dll
0x6be20000 - 0x6becb000     C:\Windows\system32\aticfx32.dll
0x4b350000 - 0x4b363000     C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives\jinput-dx8.dll
0x65ee0000 - 0x65f10000     C:\Windows\system32\DINPUT8.dll
0x68150000 - 0x68159000     C:\Windows\system32\HID.DLL
0x75900000 - 0x7592d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
0x4b430000 - 0x4b442000     C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives\jinput-raw.dll
0x63b00000 - 0x63c29000     C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\bin\natives\OpenAL32.dll
0x6a3e0000 - 0x6a452000     C:\Windows\system32\dsound.dll
0x70280000 - 0x702a5000     C:\Windows\system32\POWRPROF.dll
0x6dc60000 - 0x6dc99000     C:\Windows\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x6a630000 - 0x6a660000     C:\Windows\system32\wdmaud.drv
0x6abe0000 - 0x6abe4000     C:\Windows\system32\ksuser.dll
0x6a9b0000 - 0x6a9b7000     C:\Windows\system32\AVRT.dll
0x6a9c0000 - 0x6a9f6000     C:\Windows\system32\AUDIOSES.DLL
0x6a9a0000 - 0x6a9a8000     C:\Windows\system32\msacm32.drv
0x6a3c0000 - 0x6a3d4000     C:\Windows\system32\MSACM32.dll
0x6a3b0000 - 0x6a3b7000     C:\Windows\system32\midimap.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms512m -Xmx1024m 
java_command: C:\Users\Griffin\Downloads\Minecraft.exe
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre\bin
USERNAME=Griffin
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42 stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 6238064k(2690036k free), swap 12474276k(8122068k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (22.0-b10) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_02-b13), built on Nov 17 2011 17:17:32 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Fri May 04 12:25:11 2012
elapsed time: 193 seconds
```

Comment: Increasing ram allocation towards Java

Comment: Already tried that multiple times

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: Good question...

Comment: Still waiting for answer...

Comment: i seem to be having the same problem except no matter what i do when i check it in debug view it wont show that i have more but its not telling me that it cant run it. this is what is in my run.bat file "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Xmx2048m -Xms2048m -jar "Minecraft_Server.exe"
Pause debug says its still only running on 1gig

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have successfully solved my RAM problem! The trick is to put to do the following:

1. Download Java 64-Bit (if you have a 64-bit computer)
2. Put a Minecraft shortcut onto your desktop
3. Right click the shortcut and choose properties
4. Tell Minecraft to use 64 bit Java with the following code (put this
       code in the target):

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp
>   Minecraft.exe net.minecraft.LauncherFrame

Not only does this tell Java to use more RAM, **but also shows it the location of the 64 bit Java.**

I hope others learn from my mistakes! Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 10):

Are you running the 32-bit version of Java?  If so, download and install the 64-bit version.  32-bit Java has a fairly low limit set on the amount of memory it can allocate.

This will only work if you're running a 64-bit operating system though.

If that's not the issue, try to post the crash log if you can.  If you're using mods and have ModLoader installed, take a look at the modloader.txt file in your .minecraft folder right after a crash.  Specifically, the lines near the end of the file.  It could shed some light on your problem.

Comment: Just downloaded the 64 bit version of Java. When it got to 21%, it died. It didn't give me a message, it just died.

Comment: @parioscreations Now make sure the 64-bit version of Java is the one in your PATH, i.e., make sure it is actually being used by Minecraft. An easy way to determine this is fire up your CMD and type `java -d64 -version`. If it returns a successful message, you should be running the 64-bit version of Java.

Comment: It says it is an unrecognzed object and it could not crate the Java virtual machine

Comment: Then you have a 32-bit version installed. If your computer is 64-bit, consider installing the 64-bit version of java.

Comment: I install the 64 bit version of Java, yet it still does not recognize it! >:(

Answer (score 2):

Download a 64bit version on Java AND increase the memory limit:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar "C:\Path\To\Your\minecraft.jar"
```

Save this in a `.bat` file and you're done.

Comment: Seems like there is an error in your command.  It would seem like it would logical to increase the limit beyond what a x86 operating system supports which is 2048MB

Comment: I can't remember why I settled on this value, anyway it looks sufficient for my needs, never crashed ever since. Feel free to increase it at will. With 32bit Java I wasn't able to go past 1024M anyway. (I should also mention that at the time I only had 4GB of physical memory.)