# HD Texture Packs In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering, I have optifine and I can get HD yexture packs but if I get anything over 128x Minecraft crashes.  Why is this happening?  My computer is very new and has great proccesors and graphics cards.  My processor is an intel i7 3,4Ghz and my graphics card is a one of the higher AMD Rathelons and I usually get 200fps with Minecraft.  I also have 8GB of RAM.

EDIT: When I use mc-patcher with a 256x256 texture pack I get this error report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Would you like a cupcake?

Time: 6/23/13 7:46 AM
Description: Rendering screen

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at bio.a(SourceFile:388)
    at bio.<init>(SourceFile:136)
    at bio.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at biq.a(SourceFile:127)
    at biq.c(SourceFile:94)
    at bir.b(SourceFile:80)
    at bge.d(SourceFile:350)
    at bge.c(SourceFile:301)
    at bjx.a(SourceFile:146)
    at axt.a(SourceFile:175)
    at bjw.a(SourceFile:109)
    at bfq.b(SourceFile:768)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.K(SourceFile:597)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:526)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at bio.a(SourceFile:388)
    at bio.<init>(SourceFile:136)
    at bio.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at biq.a(SourceFile:127)
    at biq.c(SourceFile:94)
    at bir.b(SourceFile:80)
    at bge.d(SourceFile:350)
    at bge.c(SourceFile:301)
    at bjx.a(SourceFile:146)
    at axt.a(SourceFile:175)
    at bjw.a(SourceFile:109)

-- Screen render details --
Details:
    Screen name: bjw
    Mouse location: Scaled: (125, 143). Absolute: (375, 530)
    Screen size: Scaled: (427, 321). Absolute: (1280, 961). Scale factor of 3
Stacktrace:
    at bfq.b(SourceFile:768)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.K(SourceFile:597)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(SourceFile:526)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    -- System Details --
    Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
        Operating System: Windows 8 (amd64) version 6.2
        Java Version: 1.7.0_25, Oracle Corporation
        Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
        Memory: 5540872 bytes (5 MB) / 904527872 bytes (862 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
        JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
        AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
        Suspicious classes: [com.prupe.mcpatcher.MCPatcherUtils, Config, MCLogger, ...], [com.prupe.mcpatcher.mod.ColorizeItem, AAHelper, TessellatorUtils, ...]
        IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
        LWJGL: 2.4.2
        OpenGL: AMD Radeon HD 7570 GL version 4.2.12002 Compatibility Profile Context 9.12.0.0, ATI Technologies Inc.
        Is Modded: Very likely; Jar signature invalidated
        Type: Client (map_client.txt)
        Texture Pack: 1.5TP_HD_By_Lancer_256x256.zip
        Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
        Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: Specs please...

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? They can sometimes mess up HD texturepacks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Java is running out of memory:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

Even if you've got 8GB in the system, Java can't use it all unless you let it. Right now, Java is only being given the default amount that Minecraft asks for, which is not quite 1GB:

```
Memory: 5540872 bytes (5 MB) / 904527872 bytes (862 MB) up to 954466304 bytes (910 MB)
JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

That's too little to run a 256x256 texture pack. To give Java more memory, you have to [run Minecraft with a command line](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65126/minecraft-not-using-all-of-ram) (in a batch file or script) that changes those memory flags, or use one of the alternate launcher that lets you specify the amount of memory to allocate.

Comment: How exactly do I do that?

Comment: Wait the link you put is out of date.  My java folder is jre7

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: @Ethan Use that command but edit the folder so it's right, I should think. (You probably don't need the folder path anyway—my own batch file just starts with "javaw" without the whole JRE folder path and it runs fine.) Or go find a new Minecraft launcher, and look for one that let's you set the memory with the GUI. Or use a 128x128 texture pack, since on your specs you will probably not like the performance of 256x256 anyway.

Comment: Minecraft still crashes even with it linked to my 64 bit version of Java.

Comment: @Ethan Share your command line please? (It's not 64bits that will fix it, it's changing the memory allocation switches.)

Comment: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe" -Xmx1024M -Xms512M -cp Minecraft.exe net.minecraft.LauncherFrame

Comment: @Ethan The Xmx and Xms numbers are what you need to change (they are the MB of memory available to Java/Minecraft). Try setting them both to 2048.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MC-Patcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1496369-13w23b-152-151update-611-mcpatcher-hd-fix-400-beta4-304-01/). Optifine doesn't work to good with some HD texture packs.

Comment: How do I install mcpatecher and use an hd texture pack with  it?